# How to set custom message for custom validation in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have three field in my html one is mobile_min,mobile_max and third field
i have taken is test which is a input field.So what i have to do i have to
create a custom validation with custom message in which my requirement is mobile_min value should not be greater than mobile_max value after submitting the from.So my code is working fine but i am getting this message **"The Min value is not greater than max value field is required."** and but i want this message **"The Min value is not greater than max value field."**.I have also read the custom message rule of CI but it is not working.

Html field code

```
<html>
<input type=text name=mobile_min>
<input type=text name=mobile_max>
<input type=hidden name=test>
</html>
```

Controller Validation code

```
<?php


        if($this->input->post('mobile_min')>$this->input->post('mobile_max'))
     {

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('test', 'Min value is not greater than max value','trim|required');
      } 
?>
```

Please help me thanks in Advance.

Comment: show your full method pls

Comment: i have a large code in my controller after this my is like if ($this->form_validation->run()) {  //Do some thing } thats all in my method.

Comment: Try this [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-error-messages)

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475543/codeigniter-custom-validation-errors-for-each-rule-per-each-field
and 
https://arjunphp.com/custom-validation-rules-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

Use codeigniter form validation call back https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Controller function:

```
<?php 

class Controllername extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {

   $this->load->library('form_validation');
   $this->load->helper('form');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile_min', 'mobile min', 'required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile_max', 'mobile max', 'required|callback_somename');

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
      /// Success data.
   }


   $this->load->view('some_view');

}

public function somename() {
   if($this->input->post('mobile_min') > $this->input->post('mobile_max')) {

      $this->form_validation->set_message('somename', 'Min value is not greater than max value');

      return FALSE;


   } 
}

}
```

View

```
<?php echo form_open('controllername'); ?>

   <?php echo validation_errors();?>

   <?php echo form_input('mobile_min', '', array('id' => 'mobile_min'));?>
   <?php echo form_input('mobile_max', '', array('id' => 'mobile_max'));?>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```